# How to save two different checkpoints during training in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Assume we have test/val/train splits. During training, we want to save some model checkpoints [save_1] that can be used to restart the training later.

In addition, we want to save another model during training that shows the best performance on the validation sets [save_2]. After done with training, we use save_2 to report the performance on the test data.

My question is that how we can have two different tf.savers during training in TensorFlow? whatever examples that I have seen, only save [save_1].
Pointer to any codes would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get quite close by using an [Estimator](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py#L984) to wrap your model. Specifically see the options surrounding saving multiple checkpoints in [RunConfig](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/run_config.py#L182) (you don't have to throw any away). Could be combined with a [ValidationMonitor](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/monitors.py#L609) to find the lowest validation error.